# Oracle SQL -- Grabbing values from multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have a table like this:

```
TABLE: FACTS
ID       KEY         VALUE
1        name        Jeremy
1        height      5'11
1        awesomeness 10
2        name        Mark
2        awesomeness 4
3        height      4'6
```

So, the (ID,KEY) tuple can be considered as a primary key.

I am trying to return rows like this:

```
ID     NAME     HEIGHT    AWESOMENESS
1      Jeremy   5'11      10
2      Mark     (null)    4
3      (null)   4'6       (null)
```

So other than by doing a sub-select for each column, how can grab the key values, if they are there, and collect them into my single row? What I tried so far was:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CASE WHEN facts.key = 'name' THEN value END name,
  CASE WHEN facts.key = 'height' THEN value END height,
  CASE when facts.key = 'awesomeness' THEN value END awesomeness
FROM
  facts
WHERE
  facts.id in (1,2,3)
```

But for obvious reasons this returns one row per key that matches, not one row per id.

How can I go about getting this the way I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pivot the data like this in any version of Oracle.

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN key = 'name' THEN value ELSE null END ) name,
       MAX( CASE WHEN key = 'height' THEN value ELSE null END ) height,
       MAX( CASE WHEN key = 'awesomeness' THEN value ELSE null END ) awesomeness
  FROM facts
 WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
 GROUP BY id
```

If you're using 11g, you could also use the `PVOT` operator.

If this is representative of your data model, though, that sort of entity-attribute data model is generally going to be rather inefficient.  You would generally be much better served with a table that had columns for `name`, `height`, `awesomeness`, etc.

Comment: 10s ahead of me, and with a slightly tidier version of the same query :/

Comment: This is great and works perfectly, but I don't get it. What is the logic here? Why max, say, instead of min? (P.S. this table backs a system where users can create arbitrary keys so it's necessary to have it backed by something like this)

Comment: @Jeremy - Any aggregate function which returns the non-NULL value if there are multiple rowsonly one of which is non-NULL would be sufficient.  `MIN` should work just as well-- it's just conventional to choose `MAX`